# I did dependency injection but the value is returning null in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserDAService _user = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserDAService>();
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        _user.GetAdminUser(1);
        return View();
    }
}
```

`_user` returns null. So `_user.GetAdminUser(1)` also gives System.NullReferenceException error.

```
public interface IUserDAService
{
    int GetAdminUser(int id);
}

public class UserDAService : IUserDAService
{
   public int GetAdminUser(int id)
    {
        using (var connection= DBConnection.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection.CacheQuery<int>(StoredProcedure.GetAdminUser, new { Id = id }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have in your `ConfigureServices()` method? If needed, see here for the documentation on how to use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: ConfigureServices()  does not exist

Comment: `ConfigureServices()` is **essential** for configuring the Dependency Injection engine. Without it, the Resolver has no knowledge that asking for something that implements `IUserDAService` should produce a `UserDAService` object. See the page that I linked for examples.